# Vertical div with scroll fill all available vertical space

Tags: css, html

I want to create such layout:

> +-----------container-----------+
>   | +-----fixed-height-div-------+|
>   | +-------fixed-height-div-----+|
>   | +-fill-height-scrollable-div-+|
>   | +-fixed-height-bottom-div-+|
>   +---------end-container-------+

The problem is how to make *fill-height-scrollable-div* to fit all available space. See example for more details.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/SkeLLLa/fz2C7/

Are there any **not javascript** ways to set *div.chat-user-list-cnt* to fit all available height and make *div.chat-bot-btns-cnt* stick at the bottom of *div.chat-list* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your demo, everything has a fixed height except the "scrollable div", and your outer div is absolutely positioned (well, `position: fixed`, but close enough).

What you need to do is take advantage of the fact that you can set for example `position: absolute; top: 50px; bottom: 50px` on your "scrollable div".

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/UPG6A/ (simplified version)

Comment: What about if one or both of the top fixed divs have a dynamic height?